# SharePoint quick launch customization

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, quick-launch

I am in process of exploring the options for creating quick launch navigation system in SharePoint 2013 on premise. Below is requirement of quick launch navigation.

- The navigation has to be nested up to three levels deep or more.
- Each site in the SharePoint 2013 will have its own quick launch
  navigation different from rest of the sites.
- For each of quick launch menu an unqiue icon should be placed.
- Site owner should have ability to easily add new links with images to quick
  launch.

I had explored default navigation settings that would basically support only 2 levels. I am not sure Managed navigation would solve the requirement. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using managed metadata navigation. It allows for  I've added instructions and a video tutorial to help.

[SharePoint 2013 – Navigation using Managed Metadata](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15876.sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata.aspx)

[Managed Metadata Navigation in SharePoint 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ICmKCSGS7M)

You could also try building a custom menu that is based on items in a list.

[Create a Multilevel Hierarchical Menu in SharePoint 2013 with SuiteBar Branding Delegate Control](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Create-a-Multilevel-Hierarchical-Menu-in-SharePoint-2013-with-SuiteBar-Branding-Delegate-Control.aspx)

Let me know if you have any questions or need help.